# Rechart Legend masking the chart in Mobile

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Is there a way to prevent the Legend in Recharts from hiding the chart in Mobile? Please see the image below

[image: Legend overlaps with the chart itself in mobile and smaller screens]

```js
<ResponsiveContainer width='100%' aspect={5.0 / 3.0}>
    <LineChart data={dataPoints} margin={{ top: 5, right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 5 }}>
        <XAxis dataKey="Index" domain={['auto', 'auto']} label={xlabel} />
        <YAxis
            domain={['auto', 'auto']}
            tickFormatter={formatTick}
            label={{ value: ylabel, angle: -90, position: 'left' }}
        />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend iconType="plainline" />
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
        {Object.keys(linesSettings).map((line, index) => {
            return <Line
                key={index}
                dataKey={line}
                stroke={linesSettings[line].color}
                dot={false}
                strokeWidth={linesSettings[line].width}
            />
        })}
    </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally display/hide legend based on the screen size. Basically, attach a `resize` event inside `useEffect` and maintain & update a boolean state `showLegend` upon `resize`.

[Working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rechart-show-legend-issue-fix-muf4e?file=/src/App.js:0-1706)

**Code Snippet**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "recharts";
const data = [
  { name: "Page A", uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400 },
  { name: "Page B", uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210 },
  { name: "Page C", uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290 },
  { name: "Page D", uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000 },
  { name: "Page E", uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181 },
  { name: "Page F", uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500 },
  { name: "Page G", uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100 }
];
export default function App() {
  const [showLegend, setShowLegend] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      if (window.innerWidth < 800 && showLegend) {
        setShowLegend(false);
      } else if (window.innerWidth >= 800 && showLegend === false) {
        setShowLegend(true);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, [showLegend]);
  console.log(showLegend);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <LineChart
        width={600}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
      >
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <Tooltip />
        {showLegend && <Legend />}
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="pv"
          stroke="#8884d8"
          activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
        />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to still display the legend but outside of the chart. Is this possible?

Comment: hi - i can take a look later on if possible ..... since it is another question/topic to discuss, can you post another question on stackoverflow .. if the answer has helped you can consider to accept the answer.. thanks

Comment: Poor form, AissaouiA. Please be appreciative. @gdh wrote code for you and deserves an accepted answer...